# How i write this Query. Want not use Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, left-join, laravel-query-builder

Please can anyone tell me the query? I use Laravel 5.7 with mysql.

My Tables:

### users

- id
- name

### recipes

- id
- user_id
- name

### flavours

- id
- name

### flavour_recipe (pivot)

- flavour_id
- recipe_id

-A User can have many recipes(one-to-many)

-A recipe can have many flavours and a flavour can be in many recipes.(many-to-many)

How i can get all recipes(with his flavours) from a given user?
I want use the Laravel Querybuilder, not Eloquent.

I was trying this, but its not working:

```
$allRecipesFromUserX = DB::table('flavour_recipe')
        ->join('flavours', 'flavours.id', '=', 'flavour_recipe.flavour_id')
        ->join('recipes', 'recipes.id', '=', 'flavour_recipe.recipe_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'recipes.id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: This is not a question. SO is not a programming service. Please put some more effort in your question. Try something out yourself, show us what you have tried. Try reading the docs on Laravel Query Builder https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries .

Comment: I have added what i was trying ...

Comment: Ok so now you say it is not working. Do you see any errors? What is the ouput? Please provide some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want all recipes for a given user.

If i take a look at your query, you are starting from the pivot table, i dont think this is the right approach. Also you do never declare a `WHERE` clause to limit it to the specific user.

Take it step by step. You want to get everything for a specific user, so lets start with the User table

```
$allRecipesForUser = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

A User can have many recipes

```
$allRecipesForUser = DB::table('users')
    ->join('recipes', 'users.id', '=', 'recipes.user_id')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->get();
```

And a recipe can have many flavours and a flavour can be in many recipes

```
$allRecipesForUser = DB::table('users')
    ->join('recipes', 'users.id', '=', 'recipes.user_id')
    ->join('flavour_recipe', 'recipes.id', '=', 'flavour_recipe.recipe_id')
    ->join('flavours', 'flavours.id', '=', 'flavour_recipe.flavour_id')
    ->where('users.id', $id)
    ->get();
```

I hope this works out for you. Let me know if this is not what you need.

Comment: Sorry that i was not answering that time, but i was a little disapoint to get downvotes because my question had not the right format.
Today i came back and saw your answer. Thanks for that.
I found a solution on a other place that time. It was exactly what you wrote.

Comment: That is no problem. I get that it might be a bit demotivating. But, learning is key. Now you know for the next question. Keep asking and keep learning. Please mark the question as answered by selecting the correct answer. Thank you and good luck!